# Check whether the property is functional using SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I want to check whether a property is functional or not.  I tried:

```
ASK {
  pz:isBase owl:isInverseFunctional .
}
```

but it is a syntax error.  How can I check whether a property is functional?

Comment: Are you trying to see if the property is an InverseFunctionalProperty?

Comment: In general, you can check [Section 2, Mapping from the Structural Specification to RDF Graphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Mapping_from_the_Structural_Specification_to_RDF_Graphs) to find out how various OWL axioms will be mapped to RDF (and thus, how to query for them using SPARQL.)  In this particular case, the OWL axiom `InverseFunctionalObjectProperty( OPE )` is translated into the RDF triple `T(OPE) rdf:type owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ASK {pz:isBase rdf:type owl:InverseFunctionalProperty}
```

To explain: the patterns that RDF represents, and which SPARQL queries, are *triples* of `subject predicate object`, or in other words a binary predicate. You're thinking of a *unary* predicate `isInverseFunctional()`, but RDF doesn't do unary predicates. Instead, that kind of type or sortal information is encoded as a binary predicate with a special predicate `rdf:type`, which you can think of as `isKindOf` or `is member of the class`.

So, to discover whether a resource denoting a particular predicate in your domain model is an inverse functional property, you ask whether that resource is in the class of, i.e. has `rdf:type` the class of all inverse functional properties or `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`.